# How can you get an NSButton to detach from an NSStackView when the stack view resizes?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsbutton, nscontrol, nsstackview

How can you get an `NSButton` to detach from an `NSStackView` when the stack view resizes?

`NSControl` subclasses that use `NSCell` drawing seem to have a different mind than other `NSView` subclasses on visibility with compression resistance in Auto Layout.
`NSStackView` doesn't seem to make a difference here either.

If I set the Visibility Priority for a control higher than 1, it will not drop.
If I set it to 0, well, of course it will only drop and never appear.

How is this supposed to work?
What does it take to get a button or other control to drop when the stack view is resized smaller?
Maybe it's the dearth of docs and examples of `NSStackView`...

Comment: +1 for being bold and wrestling with that new `NSStackView` thingie - and the first SO stack view question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I saw any views detach, I had to do two things:

1. Call [`-[NSStackView setClippingResistancePriority:forOrientation:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstackview/1488880-setclippingresistancepriority). If the size of the stack view is tied to the size of the window, the priority needs to be less than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500) or the stack view doesn't allow the window to get smaller than its content.
2. Each time I added a view to the stack view that I wanted to detach, call [`-[NSStackView setVisibilityPriority:forView:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstackview/1488890-setvisibilitypriority) for that view.

Comment: Better late than never. Nobody was into it at the time. Now you can just set it all up in IB. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the priority to `NSStackViewVisibilityPriorityDetachOnlyIfNecessary`?

Comment: Nope. Sits there like a button does when it's constrained to both sides of a split view sub view and you drag the divider. I'm guessing there's some trick to constraint priorities next.